# Use Simple Product Pricing for Configurable Products

Tags: magento

I installed the [Simple Configurable Products](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/simple-configurable-products.html) extension for configurable products pricing.

In the description it says that we need to set-up: `System->Configuration->SCP Products`. However, in the back-end I can't see this section. Can someone help how to fix this problem?

I don't want to use tier price, so this extension seems perfect but I can't make it to work

Answer (score 0):

Please go to the System ->Configuration. Look for the "SCP" tab on the left hand-side, where you will find "SCP Config", click on that it will show the "SCP Config" Page. The "SCP Product Page" tab has got various options, which will enable you to update the simple products details accordingly.

Let me know if you don't understand my explanation.

Cheers,
Swapna

Answer (score 0):

If Swapna's note about looking in the right place didn't do it, then consider:

When you install a new module you won't see the configuration pages until you log out and then back in to the admin panel.  Give that a try.

Failing that, can you see the module in `System->Configuration->Advanced`?